# JQuery .prepend() does not work after sorting table form view One2many filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-11

I try to append inside from view have One2many filed checkbox at front, and everything work fine by using [.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/), but when the table is sorted [.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) does not work,

I want to understand why this is happening and how to solve this problem.

```
start: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self=this;

            self.$el.find('table.o_list_view tr:not(:first)')
                    .prepend($('<td class="o_list_record_selector"><div class="o_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><span></span></div></td>'));
},
```

Comment: Try triggering the event once. by using .trigger method like this 

self.$el.find('table.o_list_view tr:not(:first)')
                    .prepend($('<td class="o_list_record_selector"><div class="o_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><span></span></div></td>')).trigger("change");

Comment: @RishabhAggarwal .trigger() not working with all events.